# PhoneGap geolocation and Windows Phone8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, geolocation

According to PhoneGap documentation, the Geolocation API are not available for Windows Phone 8.

But according caniuse.com (http://caniuse.com/geolocation), the HTML5 geolocation is available for Windows Phone 8.
So, i don't understand how to implement a location function in windows Phone 8 with Phonegap.

Comment: Just because a phone has support for Geolocation doesn't mean PhoneGap supports it...

Comment: Ok,but syntax is the same and this confused me.
So, which is the method to have location coordinates in windows phone 8 (making an HTML-phonegap app)?

Comment: Probably a plugin of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Dont mind the PhoneGap documentation. PhoneGap documentations are not available for everything, and some are not even complete. So what my advice will be, "Test it yourself"..! because many functions in windows phone 8 worked for me even if there is no doucumentation.

According to this link it supports windows phone 8.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

Maybe this link will be helpful.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=953

Good Day!